# CentOS 7 - NVidea Graphic Card not switching to Intel Graphics

Tags: graphics-card, centos, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, asus-laptop

I have a notebook ASUS N46CB with CentOS 7.
This notebook has two graphic cards: an offboard NVidea Geforce GT 740M and an Intel Graphic Cards 4000. When I'm using Windows, the graphic cards are switching automaticaly. So, When I am playing a game, the notebook is using NVidea and when I am not, it's using Intel Graphics.
How do I make this on CentOS? In fact, a away to disable the NVidea GT 740M an use only Intel Graphics already would be a solution in my case.
Thank's for the help and apologize for the bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a muxless system(that means you cannot switch them into BIOS) you can install bumblebee driver and nvidia ones with your package manager (in Ubuntu it's like`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus`) .  Enter into `/etc/bumblebee` and edit bumblebee.conf, replacing `Driver=` with `Driver=nvidia` and `nvidia-current` with `nvidia-304`. After that you should reboot and you will be able to open your app using `optirun  <appl>` using the discrete nvidia card if you installed it properly.

Comment: This question is about CentOS 7 and your commands suggest a Debian-based distribution (probably Ubuntu).